# ps/2 keyboard when send commands

Tags: x86, osdev, interrupt-handling, irq

I write interrupt driven driver for ps/2 keyboard and I have basic queue of commands

In osdev wiki they say that:
`you can't start sending a command within the IRQ handler because code outside the IRQ handler may be in the middle of sending a command.`
but then, when it should be sent?
If after interrupt then how I will execute specific code after returning from interrupt?
I don't want to make it in timer interrupt because it will be a bit slower and it will waste cpu time.

Comment: You could create a task handler that runs outside the interrupt handler and does the needed processing. The interrupt handler can place device data in a queue and schedule the interrupt task to run later to process that queue. This is usually called bottom half processing. The interrupt handler is the top half and the interrupt task (that runs outside the interrupt context) is the bottom half. At one time this is how the Linux kernel worked.

Comment: When I said runs outside interrupt context, I was referring to the fact it runs outside of the device IRQ handler. The bottom half is scheduled for later so could be executed in an OS idle state or on a timer interrupt.

Comment: osdev is very generic and sometimes paranoid. How the thing goes depends on your OS/code task/thread/process handling. If you don't have a scheduler, you can have the ISR read the response data in a buffer and set a variable (eventually with a barrier). The code will send a command and then wait for that variable to be set (eventually with `hlt`/`mwait`) cycling (there's nothing else to do). If you have a scheduler you can have a function `wait_for_event` to be called after sending a command. This function will mark the process as *blocked* (i.e. not schedulable). ...

Comment: ... The ISR will read the data, buffer it and call `set_event`. This will unblock the process and do a rescheduling (picking up the waiting process if no higher ones are ready to go).  Meanwhile, other processes will be allowed to run. If you add more details about your OS we may be able to give you better solutions.